# ¿Cómo configurar los colores de un gráfico y cambiar de letra en los ejes (Vegan)?

Tags: r

Esty haciendo analisis de distinción taxonómica y este es mi codigo:

```
library (vegan)
data(plataforma)
data(plataforma.taxon)
# Taxonomic distances from a classification table with variable step lengths.
taxdis <- taxa2dist(plataforma.taxon, varstep=TRUE)
plot(hclust(taxdis), hang = -1)
# Indices
mod <- taxondive(plataforma, taxdis)
mod
summary(mod)
plot(mod)
```

Puede parecer muy básico pero mi pregunta es la siguiente: Cómo puedo cambiar el color de las lineas que da el gráfico y modificar la letra y el tamaño a los ejes por ejemplo ponerla en Times New Roman 9; ademas poner la etiqueta a cada punto que sale en el gráfico. Es esto posible?

Además me debería salir un gráfico para cada inidce

```
Species     Number of species for each site.
D, Dstar, Dplus, SDplus, Lambda     Delta, Delta^*, Delta^+, sDelta^+ and Lambda^+ for each site.
sd.Dplus    Standard deviation of Delta^+.
ED, EDstar, EDplus  Expected values of corresponding statistics.
```

Pero solo me sale un solo gráfico, como modificar para que me salga el gráfico de cada índice
Gracias de antemano

Me gustó la personalización del gráfico, pero aún me sigue quedando una duda; Yo necesito un gráfico para cada índice `(Dstar, Dplus, SDplus, Lambda)`, este es el código de vegan:

```
## Preliminary: needs better data and some support functions
data(dune)
data(dune.taxon)
# Taxonomic distances from a classification table with variable step lengths.
taxdis <- taxa2dist(dune.taxon, varstep=TRUE)
plot(hclust(taxdis), hang = -1)
# Indices
mod <- taxondive(dune, taxdis)
mod
summary(mod)
plot(mod)
```

El problema es que no veo en estas líneas como modificarla para que me salgan graficados los otros índices!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asiel, 
no sé si con esto respondo la pregunta (que no me termina de quedar claro), pero al menos te va a dar una base para personalizar el gráfico. Personalmente me siento más cómodo trabajando con `ggplot2` que con los gráficos base de R, los encuentro más fáciles de personalizar. Entonces la respuesta se limita a reconstruir el gráfico del ejemplo de `vegan::taxondive()` que se obtiene con `example(taxondive)`.

> Si estás usando otros datos ayudaría mucho que pusieras un enlace para descarga o poner un ejemplo de tus datos con `dput(head(tus_datos))`. Así como está el código que presentas no es posible reproducirlo.

## El gráfico

En https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/blob/master/R/plot.taxondive.R encontré el código para el método plot del gráfico que te interesa. Revisándolo encuentro que gráfica los puntos de `Species` y `Dplus`. La línea es el valor esperado de `Delta+` y las curvas son un intervalo de confianza calculado a partir de `sd.Dplus` (+-2).  No soy bioestadístico y no tengo la menor idea de qué significa cada cosa...

## El código

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vegan)
library(ggrepel)

example("taxondive") # Produce un objeto de la clase taxondive llamado mod

mod_df <- data.frame(mod[c(1:7, 10)]) #Paso a data.frame los datos de mod, que están como lista. Porque ggplot lo requiere.

mod_df %>% 
  mutate(piso  = mod$EDplus-2*sd.Dplus, 
         techo = mod$EDplus+2*sd.Dplus) %>%  #Calculo piso y techo del intervalo de confianza. Para geom_ribbon
  ggplot() +      
  geom_point(aes(x = Species, y= Dplus)) +   #Grafico lo puntos. Si alguna variable categórica los corta se podrían colorear
  geom_label_repel (aes(x= Species, y = Dplus, label = Species)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mod$EDplus, color = "green") + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = Species, ymin = piso, ymax = techo), alpha = 0.2) +
  theme_minimal()
```

## Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya incluye el etiquetado, aunque en este caso no es muy informativo. Se pueden agregar líneas y personalizar la tipografía con los procedimientos usuales de `ggplot`.

Comment: Me gustó la personalización del gráfico, pero aín me sigue quedando una duda; Yo necesito un gráfico para cada índice (Dstar, Dplus, SDplus, Lambda), este es el código de vegan:

Comment: Estar, Dplus, Lambda y SDplus son vectores. En `mod_df` de la respuesta verás que tienen un valor diferente en cada fila. Con ese tipo de información se puede graficar un histograma o "cruzado" con otra variable un gráfico de dispersión, como los puntos de Species y Dplus. ¿Es eso lo que estás buscando? ¿Hay algún ejemplo en línea o publicaciones del gráfico que puedas enlazar?

Comment: No encuentro algún ejemplo en línea y no puedo subir una foto!!!! Pero basicamnete es el mismo grafico de arriba, pero en ves de graficar Dplus; necesito graficar Lambda!!!!

Comment: Asiel, se puede generar un gráfico de puntos con Lambda, pero hay dos cuestiones a tomar en cuenta: 1. Para Lambda no encuentro una media o aquello que sea EDplus con respecto a ED, por lo tanto no hay referencia para graficar la línea horizontal. Lo mismo vale para  las desviaciones estándar a partir de las cuales se grafican los intervalos de confianza. 2. Lambda y ED están escalas de magnitud muy diferentes, si se grafican ambas en el mismo gráfico el resultado no se va a ver bien. PD: Puedes subir una foto usando imgur y enlazándola en la pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Usando el ejemplo del mismo paquete `vegan`, el gráfico por defecto sería:

```
library (vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.taxon)
taxdis <- taxa2dist(dune.taxon, varstep=TRUE)
mod <- taxondive(dune, taxdis)
plot(mod)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los cambios que deseas:

- Modificar el color de las curvas.
- El tipo y tamaño de letra de las leyendas en los ejes.
- Agregar una etiqueta para cada punto.

Ejemplo:

```
op <- par(family = "Times New Roman")
plot(mod, 
     col = "blue",
     cex.axis = 0.8)

x <- mod$Species
y <- mod$Dplus

text(x+.2, y, labels=format(round(y, 2), nsmall = 2), cex = 0.7)
par(op)
```

Detalle:

- Con `op <- par(family = "Times New Roman")` establecemos el tipo de letra, para cualquier salida gráfica, conviene al finalizar dejar los valores iniciales con: `par(op)`. Nota: esto es válido para Windows, en Linux sería `family = "Times"`
- El color de la líneas lo establecemos con el parámetro `col`
- No puedes indicar un tamaño en puntos, ya que el mismo es dinámico, dependerá del tamaño final del gráfico, lo que si puedes es ajustar un porcentaje de aumento/disminución del tamaño por defecto de las etiquetas de los ejes, mediante `cex.axis`, un valor `.8` será un 80% menoor del tamaño por defecto
- Para dibujar los valores de cada punto, usamos `text()`, hay que calcular los puntos `x` e  `y` que en este ejemplo, son los valores `Species` y `Dplus`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]